# Operatornorm of $(\mathbb{R}^d, \|\cdot\|_1) \to (\mathbb{R}^d, \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Determine the operatornorm of the mapping $I:(\mathbb{R}^d, \|\cdot\|_1) \to (\mathbb{R}^d, \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$!

Unfortunately I haven't many ideas for this task. I know that the definition of the operatornorm for a matrix is: $$\|A\|=\sup\{\|Ax\| \,\big{|}\, \|x\|=1\}$$ but this is not useful for me. Any hints or explanations for this?

Comment: Compute that sup with $A=I$. Test on the coordinate vectors $e_1, e_2\ldots e_d$ first, to obtain a lower bound for the sup. Then show that the lower bound is sharp.

Comment: Does $I$ refer specifically to the identity map?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh sorry, I forgot this. Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any $x$ with $\|x\|_1=1$, we have $\|x\|_\infty \leq 1$.

Comment: Okay, I see. So one can say, that $\|I\| \le 1$. Right?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: And for the second: $\|x\|_{\infty} = 1 \Rightarrow \|x\|_1 \ge 1 \Leftarrow \|I\| \ge 1$. So all in all I get: $\|I\|=1$.

Comment: That's not right; you failed to prove the other inequality. What you need for the second part is an example of a vector $x$ for which equality is achieved.

Comment: I see, may I use $x=(1,0,...,0)=e_1$ for this?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$